# What happens in this for-loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I still have a little trouble grasping exactly what happens in a for loop. Just wondering if someone would be willing explain exactly what's happening to make the output of this to equal 16? Thanks in advance!

```
var x = 1;
 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  x += 5 * i;
 }
```

Comment: What, specifically, don't you understand? There is very little here, and all of it should be easy to find in a basic JS reference (such as you could find on MDN). It doesn't even use any ES6 features.

Comment: Start with an easier `for` loop, use debugger and you will understand what happen in it

Comment: `1 + 5 * (0 + 1 + 2)`?

Comment: Have you ever tried to debug code like this, say in the Chrome web tools debugger?  That would be the simplest way to understand this.  Put in a breakpoint and step through the loop looking at the values of x and i with each execution.

Comment: @gview Thanks I will try this.

Comment: It would be best to write a small program with this code and step through it line by line to see what it’s doing.

Comment: Add a console.log(x); before and after x += 5 * i; expression. You will know what is going wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as valid as the question is for beginners, it's material that is contained within JavaScript documentation, and is unlikely to be of use to future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var x = 1;
```

The value of x is equal to one so the first iteration in your loop will say.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    x += 5 * i;
}
```

Basically this is what is happening:

The value of x is 1 and in the first iteration the value of i is 0 so

```
x + (5*0) = 1 //Because 5*0 is 0 and 0+1 = 1
```

In the second iteration the value of x 1 and the value of i is 1 so

```
x + (5*1) = 6 // Because 5*1 is 5 + 1 = 6
```

In the third iteration the value of x is 6 and the value of i is 2 so

```
x + (5*2) = 16 // Because 5*2 is 10 + 6 = 16
```

Hope this helped you understand what was happening.

Answer (score 1):

A for loop is a way to perform a set of instructions a certain number of times. In your case, you are performing an operation 3 times.

First pass: x = 1. Add (5 * 0) to x. x = 1. i is incremented by 1 and is now 1.

Second pass: x = 1. Add (5 * 1) to x. x = 6. i is incremented by 1 and is now 2.

Third pass: x = 6. Add (5 * 2) to x. x = 16. i is incremented by 1 and is now 3.

Fourth pass: the controlling variable, i, no longer meets the loop condition (i < 3) so it breaks the loop, resulting in x having a final value of 16

Answer (score 0):

Loops run for 3 times, as i value starts from 0,1,2, also the X value would become 16 at the end of the loop.

Comment: it runs 3 times.